# Executing 'ng serve' command throws 'Access is denied' error

Tags: angular, gruntjs

I am facing an issue since morning. When enter 'ng serve' command to run the angular project, I am getting 'Access is denied' error. The same issue is occurred when executing the grunt commands too. Any idea on this?

The projects were working correctly until yesterday. I have attached the screenshot for your reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have `ng serve` already running there.

You can do `Ctrl + Alt + Del` and kill any `NodeJS` instance you find.

Then try again.

If that doesn't work, check your folder permissions, and make sure you have a correct access rights to that folder.

Comment: I restarted my machine, I hope that will kill all the running process. I am able to view and create files inside the mentioned folders in the screenshot.

Comment: can you give better solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried running the command prompt as an administrator? You should click on Start -> Type CMD -> and when it finds it -> right click on it and click 'Run as Administrator'. Alternatively you can try this with PowerShell. Even better solution would be to run the NodeJS inside the Docker container. That way you avoid a lot of permission problems that might occur.